# How to add the integral after every command in python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a problem.

I want to make a list named admr but don't know how to add the integral after every command. It's too hard to explain so I write down the example below.

Could anyone help me? Thank you.

my code:

```
mr=[]

def records():
    return

def add(records):
    records = input('Add description and amount:\n').split()
    mr.append(records)

while True:
    command = input('\nWhat do you want to do (add / view)? ')
    if command == 'add':
        records = add(records)
```

what I want is:

```
input add() : Tree 50
mr = [['tree', '50']]
admr = [['tree', '50', '1']]

input add() : Fun 100
mr = [['tree', '50'],['Fun', '100']]
admr = [['tree', '50', '1'],['Fun', '100', '2']]
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
# Starting with records = ['tree', '50']
# Get length of array with len(array)
# Increment by one
# Convert to string to match your result
records.append(str(len(mr)+1))

# Ending with records = ['tree', '50', '1']
admr.append(records)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW "+1" is not necessary.